# Pyspark : Filter data based on resultant computation

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I have a data frame, which contains three columns, `timestamp, hostname, and num_denied`. I want sum up the `num_denied` based on `groupby` of `timestamp and hostname` and display result where, the `num_denied` is greater than a value (say 500000).

Example:

```
>>> df.show()  
+----------+----------+----------+  
|      Time|  Hostname|num_denied|  
+----------+----------+----------+  
|1456855800|hostname.2|       310|  
|1456855800|hostname.0|       314|  
|1456855800|hostname.0|       256|  
|1456855800|hostname.2|       304|
```

Now, When I perform -

Result:

```
df.groupBy(['Time','Hostname']).agg({'num_denied':'sum'}).show()   
+----------+----------+---------------+  
|      Time|  Hostname|sum(num_denied)|  
+----------+----------+---------------+  
|1456855800|hostname.0|        1507741|  
|1456855800|hostname.1|        1441778|  
|1456855800|hostname.2|        1428479|  
|1456855860|hostname.0|         501624|  
|1456855860|hostname.1|         504208|  
|1456855860|hostname.2|         517899|  
+----------+----------+---------------+
```

Question:
How do you further reduce the above resultant table,something like 
**Pusedo code** `df.groupBy(['Time','Hostname']).agg({'num_denied':'sum'} > 60000)` so that we get the result

```
+----------+----------+-----------------------+  
|      Time|  Hostname|sum(num_denied) > 60000|  
+----------+----------+-----------------------+  
|1456855800|hostname.0|        1507741        |  
|1456855800|hostname.1|        1441778        |  
|1456855800|hostname.2|        1428479        |  
+----------+----------+-----------------------+
```

Basically I want to filter on the aggregated value, How do it filter it? Have tried few options on filters, but wouldn't work.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
df.groupBy(['Time','Hostname']).agg({'num_denied':'sum'}).filter(df['sum(num_denied)']>6000).show()
```

https://spark.apache.org/docs/1.6.1/api/python/pyspark.sql.html

filter(condition) - Filters rows using the given condition.

```
df.filter(df.age > 3).collect()
[Row(age=5, name=u'Bob')]
```

Comment: the above command throws an error saying sum(num_denied) is not part of the dataframe (column) - 'Cannot resolve column name "sum(num_denied)" among (Time, Hostname, num_denied);'.  I can store the result in another dataframe and filter the result. Basically df['sum(num_denied)'] is not part of df. Any workaround for single line execution?